# Which CheckedListBox type control (in devexpress) allows color change for individual items?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, checkedlistbox

I am using CheckedListBox , but I need to highlight individual  items with different colors/fonts or some other highlighting method.

But it allows to change visual properties for the whole control only and not for individual items.

**Additional Info:** 
I am using 2 such lists (because need checkboxes for easier selection)  and 2 buttons (>> <<) for include/exclude type functionality. Is there any other better way to implement such whereby my requirement as above also gets fulfilled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only dabbled with DevExpress controls, but I think you have to subscribe to the `DrawItem` event and set the `e.Handled` property to true.

Something like this ([CheckedListBox items with different colors](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/6053.aspx)):

```
private void checkedListBoxControl1_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e) {
  CheckedListBoxControl clbControl = sender as CheckedListBoxControl;
  ButtonState state = ButtonState.Normal;
  if (clbControl.GetItemChecked(e.Index))
    state = ButtonState.Checked;

  ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 15, 15), state);

  string itemText = e.Item.ToString();
  Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 15, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 15, e.Bounds.Height);
  if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) != 0) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, textRect);
  }

  if (state== ButtonState.Checked)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, e.Appearance.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), textRect, e.Appearance.GetStringFormat());
  else
    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, e.Appearance.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), textRect, e.Appearance.GetStringFormat());

  e.Handled = true;
}
```